# Equivalent idiom in English

Tags: idiom-request

In my home language - Urdu, there is an idiom *“Charaney key bandar ku baraney ki rassi”.* This phrase is used to describe a situation where someone buys a monkey for one dollar, but he spends four dollars on a piece of rope to tie it.
 Basically, this is not a wise thing to do.

Could you please help me with an equivalent idiom in English?

Comment: Can you give a literal translation of the Urdu?

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-penny-wise-and-pound-foolish “'be penny-wise and pound-foolish' in British English [now old-fashioned] ...to be extremely careful about small amounts of money and not careful enough about larger amounts of money." Although the $1 monkey and $4 rope is more amusing and a better idiom, in my opinion. :-)

Comment: Can you provide the meaning or a better description of the idiom? Not a literal translation or description of it. When and why is it used?

Comment: Perhaps "throwing good money after bad"?  That is used to describe a situation in which a person has made a foolish investment and then spends additional money on it without any real hope of improving the original mistake.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest "free as in puppy" but it's not a well known expression outside of the free software community.

Comment: I second what @Max said. Please provide an explanation of when the idiom would be used. A literal translation such as the one you've provided is no help when it comes to the meaning of idioms. It's like asking Urdu speakers for an idiom equivalent to *Don't put all your eggs in one basket* by saying that the latter means *saare anDo.n ko ek hi Tokarii me.n mat Daal_naa*. That's literally correct but conveys no meaning.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but there is a classic cowboy song covered by scads of artists (Randy Travis, Tex Ritter, Gene Autry, Leadbelly, Roy Rogers, Mike Seeger , etc.)  Early on in this tale of misadventure, the singer relates that her has started up the trail _"on a ten dollar horse and a forty dollar saddle."_  Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpKdnUbxdME

Comment: @Adam Hey post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for the idiom: **A white elephant**

a possession entailing great expense out of proportion to its usefulness or value to the owner:

When he bought the mansion he didn't know it was going to be such a white elephant.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/white-elephant

Comment: While this might be correct, I suspect the idiom might have lost it's meaning in some dialects. When I hear the idiom "white elephant", I think of "an item you don't necessarily want", not "an item that causes more expense than it is worth".

Comment: @MathewAlden I agree with you, although that might also be due to "white elephant" gift exchanges.

Answer (score -1):

In English, you might

> Throw out the baby with the bathwater.

or

> Shoot yourself in the foot.

or

> Spit into the wind.

Some advice would be

> Don't buy any wooden nickels.

Comment: While these are common idioms, they don't match the requirement of spending more on necessary tools than on the item.

Comment: I agree with Chenmunka. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose I was focusing on the "basic" spec of "unwise thing to do" based on skewed priority.  I don't think we're very hip to this concept in America, where Hewlett Packard sells $20 printers and $80 ink cartridges.